# How to Access Guest Resources from Host?

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using virtualbox + vagrant to setup my dev environment. I've created a symlink at `/vagrant/.ivy2` to resource (.jar) files stored on the guest (vm) at ~/.ivy2

While the symlink works and I'm able to traverse it in the vm, host applications like eclipse do NOT register the contents of the symlink. Is there a way for me to expose the resources with the guest os home directory via symlink or otherwise to the host?

Comment: Paste your Vagrantfile`. `vboxsf` has know issues, it lacks support for symbolic/hard links, see the answer here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771926/persuading-git-to-handle-symlinks-correctly-on-vboxsf-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the latest version of Vagrant? I don't think you should be having any issues with this...

Regardless if you want to try a different method of exposing the guest to the host there are several options that you could use, depending on your preference:

- sshfs - http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html
- Samba - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba
- AFP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol